# Android Intents to pass data

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I don't know why, but this isn't working.  Can anyone see anything wrong with my code.

I have two activities and I'm passing data from two

```
public class InputActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText  number1EditText;
    EditText number2EditText;
    Button addButton;
```

InputActivity code looks like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);

    number1EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    number2EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("number1", number1EditText.getText().toString());
            mIntent.putExtra("number2", number2EditText.getText().toString());
            startActivity(mIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

AddActivity code looks like this

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView answer;
    double y=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        answer =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        String value1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("number1");
        String value2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("number2");

        answer.setText((int) (Double.parseDouble(value1)+Double.parseDouble(value2)));
    }
```

Comment: Try to do basic debugging like logging the values you want to transfer. For example: `Log.i("debug-number1", number1EditText.getText().toString());` before you start the `AddActivity`.

Comment: "isn't working" is too vague. What isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking quickly:

```
answer.setText((int) (Double.parseDouble(value1)+Double.parseDouble(value2)));
```

You're passing a `int` to the method `setText()` which happens to have an overload that receives a `int` argument for the cases when you pass the reference from a `String` in some `xml`. You may be getting a `ResourceNotFoundException`.

If you want to show a text with the sum between your values:

```
  answer.setText(String.valueOf((int) (Double.parseDouble(value1)+Double.parseDouble(value2))));
```

Just keep in mind that there are a lot of checks you have to do first, you may get another exceptions doing this kind of parse, like `NumberFormatException` for instance.

Comment: Your amazing man!  Thanks so much that was the exact problem you nailed it!  :)  That was a really big help as I'm trying to learn Android programming and that was stumping me all weekend as I was trying to learn about bundles and intents...  Thanks again :)

Comment: How do I accept the answer?  Is there a button to press on here?  I already upvoted your answer is accepting it different than doing that?